# Riemannian textbook reference request on umbilic points and totally umbilic hypersurfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

I'm doing a project exploring Riemannian immersions and submersions. In O'Neil's book, Semi-Riemannian Geometry, he mentions umbilic points and totally umbilic hypersurfaces and proves some interesting results.

I'm wondering if there is are any other good treatments of umbilic points and totally umbilic hypersurfaces, preferably in a Riemannian context rather than a Semi-Riemannian context.

Comment: For surfaces, these are standard results in every undergraduate textbook (or its exercises). In higher dimensions, you should look in Spivak's 5-volume opus, volume 3 for surfaces, and volume 4 for hypersurfaces in spaces of constant curvature.

Comment: I suggest googling for papers on umbilic points and hypersurfaces. They might cite books that cover this topic. You can also study the papers themselves.

Comment: I think *Submanifolds and Isometric Immersions* by Dajczer is what you want. There's a very recent (2019) revamped and largely extended version *Submanifold Theory: Beyond an Introduction* by Dajczer and Tojeiro. I would start checking the first book since it's so much shorter than the new version. Look into the new version if you need more details and more material later.